# Asp Webform Validation One Button multiple groups accordion tabs

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have a webform application that uses asp.net validators. I have a bootstrap accordian (or any accordian jquery etc) and I only want to validate controls that are on the visible panel. I setup a validation group for each panel. I have a single submit button.

I was using jquery to set the validationgroup property, but it seems when done this way, the button ignores the value.

I have tried validating manually but the page seems to skip validation altogether in that case. I am really banging my head against the wall.

```
<asp:button ID="btnDeleteConfirmation" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return Validate();" CausesValidation="False"/>

function Validate() {
    var isValid = false;
    isValid = Page_ClientValidate(mode);
    return isValid;
}
```

the mode is set when the tab/panel is switched, the value is correct when I check it. The function is called and the return value looks good, but the page postbacks and then i get the following expected error:

```
Page.IsValid cannot be called before validation has taken place. It should be queried in the event handler for a control that has CausesValidation=True and initiated the postback, or after a call to Page.Validate.
```

How do others handle validation client side when only one tab/panel needs to be validated and there is a single submit button?

Comment: I actually figured this out. The control(s) I was trying to validate were in a custom user control. The ValidationGroup property was not exposed on the usercontrol. I solved it by exposing the property as a public method. Another way you could solve it would be to set the validationgroup of each control inside the server control manually, but then the group is static.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in this case I set the validation groups on each section properly, then on whatever button I need to do the validation I do

```
Page.Validate(groupName);
```

Then you can call Page.IsValid and it will only use the validated group. That way you don't have to do anything else. Don't associated a validation group for your button either.

Comment: The above works, but it is worth mentioning that this is server side validation and not client side.